Efficiently De-nesting Nested Properties in JSON Deserialization for C#
As a newcomer to .NET, I'm learning to work with JSON deserialization in C#. How can I efficiently deserialize a JSON array of objects with nested properties into a list of C# instances, while effectively handling the de-nesting process?
I have a JSON array representing a list of objects with nested properties, like this:
[
  {"name":"apple","properties":{"color":"red","flavor":"sweet"}},
  {"name":"orange","properties":{"color":"orange","flavor":"sour"}}
]

I want to deserialize this JSON into a list of C# objects. The C# class looks like this:
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Flavor { get; set; }
}

It's important to note that the structure of the C# object (Fruit) differs from the structure of the JSON object. In particular, the C# object does not have a "properties" variable.
Is there a more efficient way to achieve this than manually iterating through the JSON array elements and assigning values to Fruit objects?
My Code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Flavor { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "[{\"name\":\"apple\",\"properties\":{\"color\":\"red\",\"flavor\":\"sweet\"}},{\"name\":\"orange\",\"properties\":{\"color\":\"orange\",\"flavor\":\"sour\"}}]";

        // Deserialize into a list of Fruit objects
        List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };

        var jsonObjects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonElement>>(json, options);
        
        foreach (var jsonObject in jsonObjects)
        {
            var fruit = new Fruit
            {
                Name = jsonObject.GetProperty("name").GetString(),
                Color = jsonObject.GetProperty("properties").GetProperty("color").GetString(),
                Flavor = jsonObject.GetProperty("properties").GetProperty("flavor").GetString()
            };

            fruits.Add(fruit);
        }

        // Print the fruits
        foreach (var fruit in fruits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + fruit.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Color: " + fruit.Color);
            Console.WriteLine("Flavor: " + fruit.Flavor);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}


do you want to stick with Text.Json or you open for NewtonSoft as an alternative?

@PowerMouse right now I prefer to stick with Text.Json

Create a class based on your JSON, deserialize the JSON to the objects of the created class type. Then using LINQ or mapper library such as AutoMapper to map to the Fruit objects? Efficient way? I don't know what is the definition of your efficient way here,  what you want is probably the simplest way to achieve it?

@YongShun Im just looking for an elegant (probably simple) and maintainable solution.

The shortest way (in one code line)
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

List<Fruit> fruits = JsonNode.Parse(json)?.AsArray().Select(j => new Fruit { Name = (string)j["name"], Color = (string)j["properties"]["color"], Flavor = (string)j["properties"]["flavor"], })
                            .ToList();
// or 

using Newtonsoft.Json;
                            
List<Fruit> fruits = JArray.Parse(json)
                        .Select(j => new Fruit {Name= (string)j["name"], Color= (string)j["properties"]["color"],Flavor= (string)j["properties"]["flavor"], } )
                        .ToList();

or you can wrap this code in a converter
var fruits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Fruit>>(json, new FruitConverter());

public class FruitConverter : JsonConverter<List<Fruit>>
{
    public override List<Fruit> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<Fruit> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jArr = JArray.Load(reader);

        return jArr.Select(j => new Fruit { Name = (string)j["name"], Color = (string)j["properties"]["color"], Flavor = (string)j["properties"]["flavor"], })
                   .ToList();
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<Fruit> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


You have several ways of doing it. i think i would use a custom converter for this because:

It's using Utf8JsonReader (more efficient in memory, especially in large files)
It's cleaner, your logic is encapsulated in one place


public class FruitConverter : JsonConverter<Fruit>
{
    public override Fruit Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return fruit;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "name":
                        fruit.Name = reader.GetString();
                        break;
                    case "properties":
                        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                        {
                            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                            {
                                string prop = reader.GetString();
                                reader.Read();
                                if (prop == "color")
                                    fruit.Color = reader.GetString();
                                else if (prop == "flavor")
                                    fruit.Flavor = reader.GetString();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("json is not fotmatted well");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Fruit value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WriteString("name", value.Name);
        writer.WriteStartObject("properties");
        writer.WriteString("color", value.Color);
        writer.WriteString("flavor", value.Flavor);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

